# How to set Acks=all in properties file spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I want to set acks=all property for my producer in my spring cloud stream kafka application.

I had tried like this :

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.requiredAcks=all
```

and

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration=all
```

and

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.<channel>.producer.configuration.requiredAcks=all
```

Unfortunately noting works for me.

Can you please help me how to set these kind of properties to application level or producer/consumer.

Comment: Just to be sure, are you using the Kafka binder or Kafka Streams binder ?

Answer (score 0):

The configuration below is only used by the Kafka Binders (not the kafka Streams one). It is used to set the acks property of a producer instance.

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.requiredAcks
```

To configure a Kafka Streams instance, properties must be prefixed with `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder`([Spring Cloud Stream Configuration)](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/2.1.2.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_configuration_options_2).

Into KafkaStreams, producers properties can be override by adding the prefix ".producer" (see [Configuring a Streams Application](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html); So to configure producer acks you should define the following property :

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.producer.acks=all
```

Note, that if you are building a stateful Kafka Streams application it's highly recommended to enable the *exactly_once* semantic.

This semantic can be configured with :

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.processing.guarantee=exactly-once
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I had taken example from demo of Josh Long. Here is link for properties file: [link]https://github.com/joshlong/spring-cloud-stream-kafka-streams/blob/master/analytics/src/main/resources/application.properties , here we had two producers and I want to customize properties for each producer. How can I add any required configuration for specific producer or consumer or application level?

Answer (score -1):

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.acks: all
```